# How to connect LED to output device to show the output state without any voltage drop so that it can be sensed by MCU?

Tags: voltage, led, 555

I am using an NE555 timer to get output from one of my output device. The basic function of NE555 timer here is to toggle the output of my output device which was successful but I need to attach a LED to the output of NE555 to show the output state.

When I directly connected the LED in parallel to the OUTPUT pin of NE555 and Measured voltage across OUTPUT pin and GND the voltage drops to 3.2 V but I need it to be 5 Volt so that I can sense the output of NE555 using MCU.

Can anybody let me know how to connect an LED to the output of the NE555 (Source) without any voltage drop?

Regards,
Mr.B
[image]

Comment: 3.2V should give you a Logic "1" What is the problem?  The driver Vce(sat) when high is responsible for the drop of 1.2V. You can raise this slightly with 220 Pullup to 5V if necessary.  But 3.2V seem too high for one 3mm RED LED. It should be 2.2V and white 3.2V

Comment: Thanks Mr.Sunnyskyguy. I know 3.2 V is enough but the question is why there is a drop that why I created this thread.
Regards,

Comment: I answered why yet said 3.2V is too much for Red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the "discharge" pin (pin 7) is essentially a copy of the output pin, except that it is open-collector — it can only sink current, not source it. But you could use it to control your LED without affecting the rest of your circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpFN02m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Mr.Dave Tweed ,The Circuit you gave works flawlessly
Regards,
Mr.B

Answer (score 2):

From the NE555 datasheet:

[image]

we can see that with a 5 V supply we can expect around 3.3 V at the output when loaded with 100 mA. Your LED of course consumes less current but that will not increase the voltage by much. So the behavior you see is to be expected.

I expect that **even without the LED** the voltage at the output will not reach 5 V! That's a consequence of the design of the output stage in the NE555 chip.

You might not actually need a proper "5 V" one signal, when a uC is running on a 5 V supply the actual decision point is at 5 V /2 = 2.5 V, so 3 V might be enough. That isn't a robust solution though, I would only rely on this for a prototype or hobby project, not some device which will be mass produced.

Solution 1:

Remove the LED (use a transistor to switch the LED if you still need the LED) and add a **pull up resistor** (try 1 kohm) to the NE555's output. That might raise the voltage enough.

Solution 2:

Use the CMOS version of the NE555, it is the [ICM7555](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/www/doc/datasheet/icm7555-56.pdf) that chip can pull its output close to the 5 V supply rail provided you do not draw much current from it. You will need to run the LED at less than 1 mA for that, with a modern LED, that will still be enough to see it light up.

If you really need more current through the LED, use an NPN transistor (BC547, 2N2222 for example) or N-channel MOSFET (2N7000 for example) to switch on/off the LED.

Solution 3:

Use a transistor to level shift the voltage, that will invert the signal though.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Bimpelrekkie your solution is comprehensive and clear Thanks for your detailed answer. I tried Mr. Dave Tweed's solution and it works fine. But your solution gave more insight on whats happening in my Circuit and whats my mistake. It was more than usefull Thanks a lot!!.
Regards,
Mr.B

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and simple solution, (if you don't mind an inversion of the LED function), you could just add a pull up resistor to +5V then connect the LED between that resistor and the 555's output pin. For a more modest LED current use a resistor of 270 ohms or more.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Nedd for the solution
Regards,
Mr.B